# using other packages for my own angular package

Tags: angular, package, styles, primeng

I want to create an Angular package for a project. the components of the module use `primeng` components and some global style files. I'm confused about how to add these to my package.
How can I add `primeng` package to my module? and how can I add global css files?

Comment: just install the required packages and add the styles in angular-cli.json check this [linke](https://alligator.io/angular/primeng/).

Comment: I know installing primeng for making an app. but I want to create a module. and make an angular package. that's why I'm confused

Comment: OK, i suggest you to use [ng-packagr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr) and manage the dependencies like primeng.

Comment: thanks. but what should I do about the global styles I wrote in `app\styles.css` and my images in `assests` folder? they're not in the folder of module and they're in `app` folder

Comment: Please extend your question. Angular package and angular module are different.